# If $\frac{(b−c)}{a} + \frac{(a+c)}{b} + \frac{(a−b)}{c}=1$ and $a-b+c \neq 0 $, then prove that $\frac 1a = \frac 1b + \frac 1c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, least-common-multiple

The question given is

> If  $\dfrac{(b−c)}{a} + \dfrac{(a+c)}{b} + \dfrac{(a−b)}{c}=1$ and $a-b+c \neq 0 $ then prove that $\dfrac 1a = \dfrac 1b + \dfrac 1c$

I tried to take $abc$ on the right hand side after taking the LCM, but ended up with $b^2(c-a)+a^2(b+c)+c^2(a-b)=abc$. I could not simplify any further. Please provide only hints, not complete solution.

Comment: Sry, I had to delete my post as the question requires a bit more time to solve-very good question by the way!

Comment: @John No problem. I reckoned that you mistakenly posted the answer before finishing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\dfrac{(b−c)}{a} + \dfrac{(a+c)}{b} + \dfrac{(a−b)}{c}=1$ and
$a-b+c \neq 0$

Let $b = a + c - x$ where $x \neq 0$. Then

$\dfrac{(a-x)}{a} + \dfrac{(b + x)}{b} + \dfrac{(x-c)}{c} = 1$

$\left(1 - \dfrac x a \right) + \left(1 +  \dfrac x b \right) +
    \left( \dfrac x c - 1 \right) = 1$

$\dfrac x b + \dfrac x c = \dfrac x a$

$\dfrac 1 b + \dfrac 1 c = \dfrac 1 a$

Comment: A very elegant solution

Comment: I see now that he didn't want the solution, just a hint. Is there some way I can hide the entire solution, yet make it available to those who want to see it?

Comment: Did you just use intuition to deduce that we should put  $b=a+c−x$? And can we solve the question with direct simplification, i.e without using any $x$?

Comment: @user103816 It specified $a-b+c \ne 0$, so I figured that it must be important. So I let $a-b+c = x$ and went from there.

Comment: gotta use all you got of given exercise ;)

Comment: Somebody on facebook told me another method. Add 1 to 3rd term and subtract 1 from 1st term.

Comment: @Imago and Steven, see my answer.

Comment: You can put the code `>!` before the lines you want to leave out, then they can be revealed by hovering your cursor over the resulting box.

Comment: @CliveNewstead. I tried that. It only worked for one line.

Comment: @StevenGregory: Yeah, you need to do it for each line. If you remove the blank lines in-between then it'll all appear in one box, otherwise there will be one box for each line. (I'll do it for you if you want me to - let me know!)

Comment: @CliveNewstead: Please give it a shot. I'd like to see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @StevenGregory: Huh, it does seem to be malfunctioning slightly. Which is strange because I've never had that problem before. It used to be different (grey box instead of orange, no fancy fading effects), so the high-tech hint boxes have probably come at the cost of compatibility. Boo.

Comment: Hierarchical spoilers don't work but you could try something similar to that effect, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13736/103816

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{(b−c)}{a} + \dfrac{(a+c)}{b} + \dfrac{(a−b)}{c}=1$$ Add $1$ to $\dfrac{(a−b)}{c}$ and subtract $1$ from $\dfrac{(a+c)}{b}$ We get,

$$\dfrac{(b−c)}{a} + \left[\dfrac{(a+c)}{b}-1\right] + \left[\dfrac{(a−b)}{c}+1\right]=1$$

$$\implies\dfrac{(b−c)}{a} + \dfrac{(a+c-b)}{b} + \dfrac{(a+c−b)}{c}=1$$
$$\implies + \dfrac{(a+c-b)}{b} + \dfrac{(a+c−b)}{c}=1-\dfrac{(b−c)}{a}$$
$$\implies  \dfrac{(a+c-b)}{b} + \dfrac{(a+c−b)}{c}=\dfrac{(a+c-b)}{a}$$
$$\implies  \dfrac{1}{b} + \dfrac{1}{c}=\dfrac{1}{a}$$

Yo!

Comment: I was going to add this to my answer when She, Who Must Be Obeyed dragged me off to help her go grocery shopping. I saw your answer when I got back. Nice. I gave you an upvote.